# How can I get the max char_length for all character varying columns in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to know a performant way to find the upper extent of the varying character columns in a postgres database.

Currently, I'm using a query to build a query to do this the heavy handed way.

```
select 
  'select ''' || table_name || ''',''' 
  ||  column_name || '''' || ', max(char_length(' || column_name 
  || ')) from ' || table_name || ' UNION ALL' as query
from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema = 'public'
and data_type in ('character varying','text')
order by table_name ;
```

Does any information that expresses max(char_length(column_name)) exist in an index meta table?

Answer (score 3):

The [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) concurrency model makes it impractical for the server to accurately track aggregated statistics like this (which is why even a `SELECT COUNT(*)` involves a full table scan). There's an *average* width in [`pg_stats`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-stats.html), but it's based on a random sample of records, and is not updated in real time.

The only potential optimisation I can suggest - depending on what you plan do do with this information, and/or what assumptions you can make about your data - is to use `octet_length()` instead of `char_length()`. This reports the number of bytes rather than the number of characters, which may or may not suit your needs, but it has the advantage of reading the byte counts directly from the record headers, rather than having to scan every character in every string looking for multi-byte sequences. The performance difference will be even more pronounced if any values are large enough to be [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html)ed. (Note that if you're using a single-byte [character encoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html), then `char_length()` already performs this optimisation.)